# Springboot application throws exception while trying to fetch Roles from keycloak access token

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I Created a springboot application and ran keycloak as a docker, as per instrctions given here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
While sending POST request, using access token i created manually(using REST client), keycloak not able to verify that access token.
As i understood from logs, problem is that, keycloak api not able to parse access token json becuase it use fasterxml jackson library to parse json, which don't accept json array of scope as

```
"scope":["user"]
```

due to this, keycloak api throw error

```
Caused by: org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInputException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
```

After some investigations, i found that jackson library don't accept json array in this format.

Complete logs:

```
2018-08-28 12:49:32.674 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token

org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Failed to read access token from JWT
    at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.parse(TokenVerifier.java:321) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.getHeader(TokenVerifier.java:335) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.RSATokenVerifier.getHeader(RSATokenVerifier.java:85) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:55) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:37) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:99) [keycloak-adapter-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:84) [keycloak-adapter-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:68) [keycloak-adapter-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:149) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInputException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"jti":"88d4a5ed-6902-412d-a377-d18f46008803","exp":1535460852,"nbf":0,"iat":1535460552,"iss":"http://192.168.1.216:81/auth/realms/demo","aud":"demo-web","sub":"592b27a5-c58b-42a3-b896-f2169448873e","typ":"Bearer","azp":"demo-web","auth_time":1535460532,"session_state":"3fb7f93b-05de-45e3-b45b-8fa555854860","acr":"1","allowed-origins":[],"realm_access":{"roles":["user","register"]},"resource_access":{"demo-web":{"roles":["user"]}},"scope":"","scope":["user","register"],"name":"demo user","pr"[truncated 115 bytes]; line: 1, column: 459] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken["scope"])
    at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.readJsonContent(JWSInput.java:104) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.parse(TokenVerifier.java:319) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"jti":"88d4a5ed-6902-412d-a377-d18f46008803","exp":1535460852,"nbf":0,"iat":1535460552,"iss":"http://192.168.1.216:81/auth/realms/demo","aud":"demo-web","sub":"592b27a5-c58b-42a3-b896-f2169448873e","typ":"Bearer","azp":"demo-web","auth_time":1535460532,"session_state":"3fb7f93b-05de-45e3-b45b-8fa555854860","acr":"1","allowed-origins":[],"realm_access":{"roles":["user","register"]},"resource_access":{"demo-web":{"roles":["user"]}},"scope":"","scope":["user","register"],"name":"demo user","pr"[truncated 115 bytes]; line: 1, column: 459] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken["scope"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1138) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(StdDeserializer.java:674) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:40) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
    at org.keycloak.util.JsonSerialization.readValue(JsonSerialization.java:69) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.readJsonContent(JWSInput.java:102) ~[keycloak-core-4.3.0.Final.jar!/:4.3.0.Final]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `using access token i created manually`: How would you manually create an access token? Access tokens are actually delivered by and only by Keycloak. Also, an access token is not a plain JSON, so you shouldn't be sending it as that: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/sso-protocols/oidc.html

Comment: I mean that i didn't integrated it in an application yet, just created using rest client, and i sent that access token in Authorization header as bearer token.

Comment: That process is fine that's why access token is decoded fine, my problem is that, keycloak api(using fasterxml jackson) not able to parse decoded access token json